# React Native admob, Internal Error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, admob

When I test banner ads with test with test ad id everything works great, but when I use my real `ad unit id`, I receive this error as below:

> Internal error, an invalid response was received from the ad server.

How can I make it work with real id?

```
<AdMobBanner
  adSize="fullBanner"
  adUnitID="ca-app-pub-1xxx/5xxx"
  testDevices={[AdMobBanner.simulatorId]}
  onAdFailedToLoad={error => console.error(error)}
/>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpWH0.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

If the ad unit was just created please wait a bit because it takes some time to start working after verfying your payment details. If you have not already added the payment details go to Home page of Admob site and do the following steps.

1) Click Home page,
error this:

Your ad units are not displaying ads because you haven't provided your account payments information yet.

2) Click Fix It.

3) Click Select Payment,

4) And Submit.

Within 24 hours, your verification mey be done and ad will be published.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my app. You just need to wait for a little. Your ad id is newly created so it will take some time to fetch ads from google servers. So give it some time and it will work soon. the first day I will try with my AdMob account its say "Internal error, an invalid response was received from the ad server." on next day try with run-android it's working fine for me. please wait for some time max 1 day after the create AdMob banner add after it's work.

Answer (score -2):

Thy to removing onAdFailedToLoad

Comment: is that a solution?